# session.save_path shows 'no value' in phpinfo() even after setting it in php.ini file.

Tags: php, session

I was getting this error upon starting phpmyadmin on macOS High Sierra:

> session_start(): open(SESSION_FILE, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13)

Later I found out that the session.save_path was set to "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp" but the phpinfo() displayed:

> session.save_path  no value    no value

I tested it by changing the path to another directory but it did not work and I am still getting the same 'no value'.

**As a result I am unable to use session functions in any project.**

Answer (score 0):

You cat set session save path before running session start function, **in you php application**, for example:

```
ini_set('session.save_path','/var/tmp/');
```

OR

```
session_save_path('/var/tmp/');
```

OR **in php.ini file**:

```
session.save_path = "/var/tmp/"
```